# jQuery: Handle multiple JSON data

Tags: jquery, json

My code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'online.php',
    success: function(data) {
        var userOnline = $.parseJSON(data);
        $('#usersOnline').append($('<div id="usersOnlineUser">').text(userOnline['username']).append($('<span class="badge">').text('aktiv')));
    }
});
```

JSON:

```
{"username":"Aarivex","active":"1"}
```

It works fine. But how i can handle it with multiple JSON data, like

```
{"username":"Aarivex","active":"1"}{"username":"Aarivex2","active":"1"}
```

?

Comment: Start returning an array of them. Then iterate them. It will work for 1, it will work for n. For example: `[{"username":"Aarivex","active":"1"},{"username":"Aarivex2","active":"1"}]` and `[{"username":"Aarivex","active":"1"}]`

Answer (score 1):

If we assume your data is:

```
var data = [{"username":"Aarivex","active":"1"}, {"username":"Aarivex2","active":"1"}];
```

Your success function becomes:

```
success: function(data) {
   $.each(data, function(index, element) {
      $('#usersOnline').append($('').text(element['username']).append($('').text('aktiv')));
   });
}
```